# Why did Odin turn into sparkles?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-ragnarok, odin

In *Thor: Ragnarok*, Thor and Loki find Odin in Norway, but he's at the end of his life and after some heartfelt words, he dies. But instead of having his body fall to the ground, he turns into sparkles, which seems at least a little bit surprising to the brothers as they stand up suddenly to watch them float away.

Why did Odin turn into sparkles instead of just keeling over like us mortal humans? Do all Asgardians do that or was it something special about him?

Comment: That's just what gods do. They turn to sparkles or gold dust or flower petals 
 or whatever, and vanish in the wind.

Comment: He is the all-father after all. He's bound to do something special (even at death)

Comment: Same thing happened at the funeral in The Dark World.

Comment: Later in the film we hear Thor praying for him on his trip to Valhalla. Maybe that is where he went...

Comment: He became a Force Ghost.

Answer (score 2):

The gods have a certain force in their essence called life-force. In Avengers age of Ultron the deleted scene with Thor in the Norn cave we see him explaining to Dr. Erik Selvig about his life force being stronger than most. This is why they tend to live much longer than the average human.

In the comics Odin's life force is called the odin force. Unlike humans, which are composed matter, they are composed of energy. The dust-like particles you see ascending from Frigga and Odin were energy being released back into the atmosphere.

Comment: I like your answer, but could you find some sources to mix in? comic pages or etc.